# Target not defined react

Tags: reactjs

sorry for the noob question, but I am getting a target undefined. I've tried passing the componentDidMount on my onformsubmit however React is telling me the query variable is not defined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

 import DisplayData from './DisplayData';


export default class stockSearch extends Component {
   state = {
       searchResult: {},

   }

   componentDidMount = (e) => {
    const query = e.target.elements.query.value


    fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT&tsyms=USD`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({ searchResult: data });
        console.log(this.state.searchResult);

    });
}

render() {
    const { searchResult } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.componentDidMount}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search Crypto" />
        </label>
        <button>Search Crypto</button>

        <DisplayData results={searchResult} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` is a lifecycle method. Not sure why you put it as `onSubmit` action handler. You need to create a method for `onSubmit` separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is one of the React Component lifecycle methods so you shouldn't pass it as the onSubmit handler. Instead, you should create a new method, e.g `fetchData`, which you pass to the form's `onSubmit`.

If you want to also fetch data on mount, you can call your handler in `componentDidMount`

```
export default class StockSearch extends Component {

  state = {
    searchResult: {},
    queryValue: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchData('default');
  }

  fetchData = (query) => {
    fetch(`http://something.com/${query}`)
      .then(...)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ searchResult: data })
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => fetchData(this.state.queryValue)}>
        <input
          value={this.state.queryValue}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

A few other things I've changed:
1. React components should be UpperCamelCase
2. Generally you'll manage state in your component, for example input values
.

Comment: Oh cool thanks, how can I pass that variable into the lifecycle method?

Comment: Updated the question to include more info!